# rewritecond in .htaccess using patterm matching

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to put together a rewrite condition in to match the last section of a URL that ends in 10 alphnumeric characters like:

http://www.someurl.com/EHN4K5LFWQ

and route it to:

http://www.someurl.com/index.php/EHN4K5LFWQ

I've put together the following so far but I can't seem to get it to work after struggling for a couple days using a number of variations both with and without a rewrite rule.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^dir1/dir2/([A-Z,0-9]{10})$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  dir1/dir2/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the htaccess file is in your document root, you can simply use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^dir1/dir2/([A-Z,0-9]{10})$ /dir1/dir2/index.php/$1 [L]
```

If the htaccess file is in the **dir2** folder, then you can use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Z,0-9]{10})$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Great. I actually just stumbled across my own answer.  It turns out I just needed to put a directory specific .htaccess fine my dir2 and then simplify my rule: 

RewriteRule ^/*([A-Z,0-9]{10})$  index.php/$1

Thanks for your help.